# How to specify that a method argument implements a trait and is a specific type?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a library that implements two traits:

```rust
pub trait Creature {
    // fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
    // etc
}

pub trait Environment {
    fn update(&mut self, creature:&impl Creature);
}

pub struct World <E:Environment, T:Creature> {
    pub environs: E,
    pub creatures: Vec<T>,
}

impl <E:Environment, T:Creature> World<E, T> {
    pub fn update(&mut self) {
        for creature in self.creatures.iter() {
            self.environs.update( creature );
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use my library like so:

```rust
use my_library::{Environment, Creature, World};
struct Dog {
    velocity: f32,
}

impl Creature for Dog {}

struct Env {
    avg_vel: f32,
}

impl Environment for Env {
    fn update(&mut self, dog: &impl Creature) {
        self.avg_vel = 0.; // want to access dog.velocity here. 
    }
}
```

I do not want the library to know or care about `velocity` or `avg_vel`.

Is there a way to write this code, such that I can access the internals for `Dog` from inside the `update` method for `impl Environment for Env`?

To rephrase, I want to couple the concrete type of the `world.creatures` objects, to the type that the `world.environs.method` argument receives.

It seems like it should be possible, from a computational safety point of view.

Comment: `fn update(creature: &impl Creature)` states that this function can accept **any type** that implements `Creature`. By definition, `fn update(dog: &Dog)` does not accept any type, it only accepts exactly `Dog`. If you don't want the behavior of a trait, don't use traits.

Comment: *access to any of the dog internals, which I need* — flip the problem around the other way: implement more methods on `Dog` or its traits. In this case, move anything that needs to know about `Dog`'s internals to `Creature`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help. I would like to rephrase the question to clarify what I'm trying to do. Do I delete this question and add a new one, or should I just edit it?

Comment: The problem is, the traits are in a separate library. If I put more methods in `Dog`, the library won't know about them. I want the user of the library to be able to access the internals inside of `Dog` (or whatever object they've used to implement `Creature`) from inside the `process` method (defined in the `Environment` trait). This method needs to be inside the `Environment` trait because I need the library to call that method.

Comment: Feel free to drastically edit a question until you have an answer

Comment: *If I put more methods in `Dog`, the library won't know about them* — continue reading what I said: "implement more methods on [...] its traits. In this case, move anything that needs to know about `Dog`'s internals to `Creature`.". Your `impl Creature for Dog {}` can access the internals.

Comment: You may be looking for Associated Types here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html But, I would be very careful before building a system that requires associated types. They're more complicated than people expect. Often when you start reaching for them, it's because you've mis-designed your traits (or even more often: created traits you don't need at all).

Comment: Yes, `impl Creature for Dog {}` can access the internals. But that is not the only place I need to access them. I need to access `Dog`s internals inside the `impl Environment for World {}`. All the `Dog`s will share the same `World`. So while the library is looping through the `Dog` objects, it also needs access to the `World` object to compute values based on both the state of the world and the state that particular dog. But the library should know nothing about what those states look like or how they're calculated. I'll try to rephrase the question. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Associated Traits

my_library: (rust version 1.56.1)

```rust
pub trait Creature {
    // fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
    // etc
}

pub trait Environment {
    type CCT; // Concrete Creature Type
    fn update(&mut self, creature:&Self::CCT);
}

pub struct World <'a, E:Environment, T:Creature> {
    pub environs: &'a mut E,
    pub creatures: Vec<T>,
}

impl <'a, E:Environment<CCT = T>, T:Creature> World<'a, E, T> {
    pub fn new(env: &'a mut E) -> Self {
        Self { 
            environs: env, 
            creatures: Vec::new(), 
        }
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self) {
        for creature in self.creatures.iter() {
            self.environs.update( creature );
        }
    }
}
```

Note, `<CCT = T>` in the impl World. It says, "Hey, your Environment is going to use the specific type of creature that the World is instantiated with."

And the relevant usage:

```rust
use my_library::{Environment, Creature, World};
struct Dog {
    velocity: f32,
}

impl Creature for Dog {}

struct Env {
    avg_vel: f32,
}

impl Environment for Env {
    type CCT = Dog;
    fn update(&mut self, dog: &self::CCT) {
        self.avg_vel = dog.velocity; // Yay, we have a dog!
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let mut env = Env { avg_vel: 0. };
    let mut world :World<Env, Canvas> = World::new( &mut env );
    world.environs.avg_vel = 5.; // And we can still do this too!
    ...
```

There may be other solutions that do not use associated traits, but this works for now.

(Thanks to Rob Napier for the suggestion!)

Comment: Note, I could only get this to work where `environs` is borrowed. I tried to give ownership to `World`, and it compiles, but I get a ... wait for it ... `Stack Overflow` error when calling `World::new( env )`. I'm not fully sure why. If I add an `init` method to the `Environment` trait, and then create a new value for `environs` inside the `World::new()` method, then it works without a borrow. I'll leave it as is for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you define a trait that has an `update` method to which you can pass anything that is a `Creature`; at least this is what your trait says.

When you implement that trait on `World`, then you say only `&Dog` can be used as a parameter here.

In your case, yes, every dog is a `Creature`, however not every `Creature` is a `Dog`. You have conflicting requirements there. Your implementation should match your trait.

Comment: Great point, it helped me realize the solution. So that now, instead of using a trait in my `update` method, I can now use a concrete type that implements that trait.